# Is the bound $g(G) \leq 2 \text{ diam}(G) + 1$ in Graph Theory best possible bound?

Tags: graph-theory

Is the bound in next proposition best possible?

> Proposition. Every graph G containing a cycle satisfies $g(G) \leq 2 \text{ diam}(G) + 1$

Question: How to prove that this proposition is best possible bound? I mean what kind of tools do I need to prove that this is optimal or not, for me I tried by just thinking and drawing all possible where girth and diameter become so close and see whether the gap is too big or not. If it is too big, then this would tell us that this is not the optimal. Is this the right way to prove bounds in graph theory?

This is how I tried...
This proposition isn't optimal. Why? Suppose we have n vertices, all of which are connected in circle, so the $g(G) = n$, then the diam$(G)=n-1$, if you add more vertices and keeping the girth the same, then the only change will be the diameter which would be greater value. Thus, if you apply these parameters (i.e. $g(G) = n$ and diam$(G)=n-1$) to the theorem, we would get the following

$$
g(G)  \leq  2 \text{ diam}(G) + 1 \\  
n \leq 2 (n-1) +1 \\
n \leq 2n -1
$$
Thus, we can see that there is almost n gap between the two sides, so obviously it is not a tight bound. Therefore, it is not possible bound.

Is this right?!

Comment: I think you might be confused about the definition of the diameter. In a cycle with $n$ vertices, the diameter is not $n-1$.

Comment: Watch out, $\text{diam}(G) = \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor$.

Comment: @pi66 you're right, I thought that the diameter is only the greatest distance between any two nodes and I forget that it should be also the shortest path if there is more than one path. Thank you

Comment: @user777 You're welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bound is the best possible: look at a graph just containing a cycle with $2n+1$ vertices. The girth is $2n+1$ while the diameter is $n$.

Answer (score 2):

To prove that this is the optimal bound, you have to find a graph such that the bound is attained with equality. If you have no graph fulfilling this condition, that means the bound is not optimal, since the actual bound minus 1 is still a valid bound.

So, can you find a graph such that $g(G)=2\mbox{diam}(G) +1$ ? You don't have to look for a complex one.

Comment: This means that what I did is the right way to see whether it is optimal or not. i.e. to find a way which diameter and girth become close in order to see whether there is a big gap or not. I think the best graph that tell us that this bound is optimal is by all vertices are connected to make a big circle, then $g(G) = n$ and diam$(G) = \lfloor n/2  \rfloor$ therefore applying the theorem we would find that there is only 1 factor in the RHS which exactly agree with the condition of the theorem